# VB.NET Equivalent to Var_dump($myVar); Die(); 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In PHP, one can immediately stop the execution of the script and output a variable.  For instance if you want to know what's in $myVar, you could do:

var_dump($myVar); die();

Is there anyway to immediately get the value of a variable and then kill it in VB.NET?

I'm not asking for a function to include necessarily; just if there is a native function that will basically output a var immediately, without me having to add it to the controller, then the view, then publish and test.  Ideally, it would just output the variable in a debugger or messagebox or something...

I am also using ASP.NET MVC 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [System.Diagnostics.Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace) and [System.Diagnostics.Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug) classes to print out information.

Stopping the execution typically occurs by either returning a relevant [System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult), such as [System.Web.Mvc.HttpNotFoundResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.httpnotfoundresult) or by throwing a [System.Web.HttpException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpexception) with the [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) which best describes the problem.

Here's a naive example. Excuse my poor VB.

```
Public Function UpdateUser(id as Integer, userName as String, password as Password) as ActionResult
    Dim user as User = DataServices.GetUserById(id)
    If user Is Nothing Then
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Aborting because user did not exist.")
        throw new HttpException(404, "Page not found.")
    End
    ' Do more stuff
end
```

Or in C#

```
public ActionResult UpdateUser(int id, string userName, string password) {
    var user = DataServices.Users.Where(u => u.id == id).SingleOrDefault();

    if( user == null ) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Aborting because user did not exist.");
        return HttpNotFound(); // Helper method in Controller Class.
    }
    else if( myRoles() < thisUsersRoles(user) ) {
        Debug.Writeline("Aborting because insufficient access.");
        throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized");
    }

    // update user here
    return View();
}
```

Note that these examples are contrived only to display the use of Debug and the return of http status codes.

Comment: So could one write some very short code to get a variable out put and the program stopped?  Could you show me what this would look like?  I'm just looking for a quick way to debug as I had in PHP, with VB.

Comment: I wanted to give you an example but I write in C#, not VB. I'll give it a shot in C# and maybe it'll give you an idea.

Comment: Note that when you call Debug.Write or Debug.WriteLine, it prints to the Visual Studio "Output" window, which by default is anchored to the bottom of your screen, near or behind the error page. You must have the debugger running.